# Setting different Window size for `Stack Windows`

Tags: mac-os-x, menu

I think someone has asked this in the past (maybe me), but I don't remember an answer or workaround.

When selecting `Stack Windows` from the menu bar e.g.

[image]

does any way exist to re-set the size of the resulting stacked windows?

As default sized they just take up too much desktop space:

[image]

I can't find anything obvious in `Option Inspector`.

Admittedly, just a little thing, but it would save me re-setting each stacked window one-by-one to regain desktop space.

While I've asked...specifying where the windows would stack would prove very useful.

Comment: My _guess_ is that this is a macOS feature, not a Mathematica feature.

Comment: That's not a window option under 12.3 under Linux (and I don't remember it on Windows)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, we'll manipulate Mathematica, so when you click `Stack Windows`, the current `WindowMargins` will be saved, and by clicking `Restore Previous Arrangement` (which will be defined) we restore the positions.

Find file `MenuSetup.tr` (Windows folder: `Mathematica_directory\12.3\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows`), find for `Stack Windows` (windows: `Stack`) and replace it with these two `MenuItem`

```
MenuItem["Stack Windows", KernelExecute[CompoundExpression[FrontEnd`lastWindowMargins = AbsoluteCurrentValue[Notebooks[], WindowMargins], FrontEnd`lastWindowSize = AbsoluteCurrentValue[Notebooks[], WindowSize], FrontEndTokenExecute["StackWindows"]]],MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
MenuItem["Restore Previous Arrangement",KernelExecute[MapThread[(CurrentValue[#1, WindowMargins] = #2; CurrentValue[#1, WindowSize] = #3) &, {Notebooks[], FrontEnd`lastWindowMargins, FrontEnd`lastWindowSize}]],MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
```

[image]

Notes:

- Tested on Windows 10 with Mathematica 12.3
- Do not click `Restore Previous Arrangement` without clicking `Stack Windows` first (it won't crash, `Messages` pops up)
- Also don't create/open or close a file after clicking `Stack Windows`, if you want to click `Restore Previous Arrangement`
- First time clicking `Stack` will be a bit slower

Comment: +1 for innovation.  Unfortunately, I run on macOS which has everything in different files and folders.  I found the entry for `MenuItem[Stack Windows (windows: Stack)]` & replaced it with your suggested code.  Saved.  Started Mma fresh.  Didn't work.  I likely missed something.  Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Comment: @Jagra Because the menu bar is language-dependent, are you sure you edit the default `menusetup.tr`, not those within Spanish or other languages folders? on Windows, there is a `...\Windows\menusetup.tr`, `...\Windows\Spanish\menusetup.tr` and 5 other languages, each with a `menusetup.tr` file.

Comment: Under macOS one finds this under the `Mathematica.app -> FrontEnd -> TextResources -> Macintosh -> MenuSetup.tr`, where one finds: `MenuItem["Stack Windows", "StackWindows"]`.  Sees like the right thing.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Jagra it seems you'd found the right file and the right line. I don't have access to a MacOS to test. but if you found the solution, feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I may have, "...found the right file and the right line.", but it doesn't work ;-(  Maybe someone else with a Mac will find an answer.  Thanks for the effort.