# How can I define a shortcut key to clear all the variables defined so far?

Tags: keyboard, command-line

In my computation I often use the command `ClearAll["Global*"]` to eliminate all the variables I have defined so far. But to input stroke by stroke is burdensome when you need to execute it so often. As a result, I am seeking to define a shortcut key which enables me to execute this command efficiently. It would be better if it can be incorporated into the init files.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I tend to `Quit[]` instead because it is guaranteed to erase every little thing.

Comment: A shortcut key always gets pressed accidentally. To task it with erasing all variables would be considered a sub-optimal GUI feature.

Comment: You may always define an alias like e.g.: 'cl:= ClearAll["Global*"] '

Comment: @DanielHuber But this will not work. Since issuing `cl` first time after it was defined, will also clear `cl` itself. So the definition is lost and have to be typed again and we are back to square one.

Comment: Right, you must define it in a different context.

Comment: @Daniel Huber. I tried to define it in a different notebook and invoke it in the current one, but it was still be erased after the first invoking.

Comment: @Roman The reason why I prefer an alias or shortcut is that there are several functions defined by myself pre-loaded from other notebooks, I do not want to erase them. `ClearAll["Global*"]` is very good at doing so, clearing all the variables but keeping the user-defined functions from other notebooks.

Comment: Hi Albert, you must define the alias in a different context, not a different notebook. E.g.:  ' Begin["MyContext`"];
cl := ClearAll["Global`*"];
End[];
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "MyContext`"]'  Note the backtik after MyContext is not showing in this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249856/setting-different-window-size-for-stack-windows), we discussed adding another option for restoring stack windows, which it seems only works on windows. The process is the same, besides the command that should be executed.

Open this file (assuming you installed Mathematica on `C` drive):

```
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.3\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\MenuSetup.tr"
```

> There are also `MenuSetup.tr` for other languages.

Find `Menu["&Edit",` and add this after `Redo`:

```
MenuItem["Clear All", KernelExecute[ClearAll["Global`*"];], MenuKey["C", Modifiers->{"Command","Shift","Control"}], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
```

> The code uses `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` to clear all the variables define in the `Global` context, feel free to change it.
> Also, I'm not sure whether Alt+Ctrl+Shift+C conflicts with other commands. I tried to pick a hard one.

[image]

If you found a solution for macOS, feel free to edit or comment on the post.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I did as what you said but it did not work at first several attempts. My intuition told me maybe it was the problem of the lowercase letter in the shortcut key, since I noticed in other shortcut combinations the letter is always in uppercase as long as there is a modifier "Shift". So I tried to modify the "c" to "C" and it works since.

Comment: @AlbertLew Thanks for the suggestion.