# Error message window upon launching Mathematica

Tags: warning-messages, system, menu

Upon launching *Mathematica* (v. 11.3) I always get the ***Messages*** window with "An unknown menu command token (RebuildHelpIndex)...", as shown below.

[image: Error window]

How do I eliminate that?

Comment: I don't have 11.3 nor insight on this command but I've used `MenuSetup.tr` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249873/77079) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255405/77079), you may want to find the file `MenuSetup.tr` (although there were some challenges on MacOS) and look for the word `RebuildHelp...`, make the line comment as you do in a notebook `(* *)` and restart the Mathematica. I hope it helps.

Comment: @BenIzd:  Thanks for your thoughts and suggestions, but alas the only MenuSetup.tr on my computer is 17 years old, buried deep in backup files, and hence irrelevant to my current problem.